# is there a Session variable in Hibernate or Java similar to PHP $_SESSION

Tags: java, hibernate, session, javafx, hql

I'm using JavaFX+Hibernate to create a desktop app,however after the user logged in with his/her **username**, I want the username to be assigned to a global variable similar to PHP `$_SESSION` variable that can be accessible from anywhere.

this is my code for the HibernateUtil.java class

```
package models;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){

     try{
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
         System.out.println("creating SessionFactory using HibernateUtil.java");
         SessionFactory f = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
         System.out.println("session created successfully");
         return f;
     } catch (Throwable ex){
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  

     }

    }

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's equivalent of a "global variable" may be a `public` accessible static variable. You could create one in your code as

```
 public class Globals {
     public static String userName;
 }
```

And the username can be set and read from `Globals.userName`.

Note: Using a `private` field and `get` and `set` methods would be more clean....

Comment: This is bad practice, and probably shouldn't be suggested here, even with the caveat you provide.

Comment: I take this answer as Yes because it's it answers the alternative to `$_SESSION` in PHP in Java ,but I will use either dependency injection or create my own method with private variables .

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "global data". Instead, just arrange to pass the username (and other data) to whoever needs access to it. (In other words, use dependency injection, in some form.)

One (of many) problems with global data is that you restrict yourself to only ever having one value for that variable. Suppose in a few months your boss comes to your office and says something like "Our clients love the application you wrote, but many of them have multiple accounts that they want to access at the same time. Can you adapt the app so that they can open multiple tabs and log into each account in a different tab?". (This exact situation might not apply to you, but the general principle does.) If you have made the username a single global variable in your application, it will be virtually impossible to make this change without rewriting arbitrarily large portions of the code.

See, e.g. http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil, and many others that you can search for, for other reasons not to do this.

Comment: thanks James,yes I understand you ,but in my case  it's a desktop App not a web server app,so the "global variable data"  will be stored in the client computer RAM ,so global should be fine in my case right ? please advice

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna Absolutely not. The advice on global data applies to software design in general. The hypothetical scenario I suggested was intended to refer to a desktop application. Don't use global data.

Comment: what about creating my own method to store the username and the username variable will be private ? I think the app will be still can handle multiple user  right ?

Comment: Where will the method be defined, and how will other parts of your application access it? That is a good idea (actually, you are talking about defining a model, in MVC terms), but you still have the same problem you started with: you have to provide the object defining those methods to other parts of your application (use dependency injection...).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Session is absolutely different from what you think.

As long as you have a desktop application you have to care what you need to keep in memory. You can create your own kind of Context or "Session" if you'd like name it that way and keep there what you need.

Analog for PHP $_SESSION exists in J2EE Web application with Servlet API